# Prevent PDF link from being shared

Tags: wordpress, hotlinking

There is a pdf on the server that we want users to access only those with the link is there any way we can prevent from being shared as well? So if the users want to share the link it will redirect them to the homepage. I know users can download and share it amongst themselves, that is something we can't prevent but I at least want to prevent them from sharing the URL. I tried to prevent hotlinking but most of the tutorials and resources I found prevent all PDFs from being shared.

Comment: Reliably?  The closest you might get is only allowing downloads for users that have established a session.  If you don't require a login or something to see the link, then...eh.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a long shot. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response but you can easily use the HTTP REFERER field to prevent access to a link from outside certain pages - SpeedFan does this for their installer download links.